# Why does disabling writing to the depth buffer cause almost nothing to be drawn?

Tags: opengl

Following [SigTerm's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9353666/65387), I render all my opaque polygons first, and then I disable the depth buffer (`glDepthMask(GL_FALSE)`) before I render my translucent polygons.

As soon as I disable the depth buffer though, it stops drawing anything to the screen. I can only see a glimpse of the world as I move the camera around (only little pieces show up for a second, and then disappear when I stop moving).

If I leave the depth buffer enabled the whole time, everything renders fine, it's just not as nice as I'd like ([translucent objects obscure other translucent objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9mEZ.jpg)).

How do I get it to render properly?

My main render loop looks like this:

```
protected void RenderTerrain()
{
    GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
    GL.Enable(EnableCap.CullFace);

    _bfShader.Use();
    _bfProjUniform.Mat4(_viewMat * _bfProjMat);
    _bfTex.Bind();

    GL.DepthMask(true);
    GL.Disable(EnableCap.Blend);
    _blendUniform.Set1(false);
    _bfVao.Bind();
    GL.DrawElementsInstancedBaseVertex(BeginMode.TriangleStrip, SharedData.FaceIndices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, IntPtr.Zero, _bfInstBuf.Length, 0);

    GL.DepthMask(false);
    GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);
    _blendUniform.Set1(true);
    _transVao.Bind();
    GL.DrawElementsInstancedBaseVertex(BeginMode.TriangleStrip, SharedData.FaceIndices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, IntPtr.Zero, _bfTransBuf.Length, 0);
}
```

---

The other half of the render loop:

```
protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
{
    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
    lock(_renderQueue)
    {
        while(_renderQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            _renderQueue.Dequeue().Invoke();
        }
    }
    RenderTerrain();
    RenderHUD();
    SwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to disable depth testing via `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`? The symptoms also indicate you not clearing your depth buffer. Clear both the color and depth buffer using `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)`.

Comment: Or set `glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS)` perhaps?

Comment: @StevenLu: Disabling the depth test does [exactly what I thought it would](http://i.imgur.com/iabpz.png). I need the depth test so that it doesn't appear in front of my opaque objects. And yes, I'm clearing both buffers.

Comment: @BrettHale: `glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS)` has the same effect as Steven's suggestion.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Can you reenable the glDepthMask before calling glClear(), or at the end of your render loop?

Preventing writes to the depth buffer will prevent it from being correctly cleared.

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/FAQ#Masking

Comment: Bingo! That looks like it was the issue. Wouldn't have thought of that.

Comment: ... this took me 1 day. A external framework disabled DepthMask, so my clearing didn't work. thanks a lot.