# OpenGL transparency and depth issues with three.js

Tags: opengl-es, three.js, webgl

I'm using three.js for a small game which utilizes textures with transparency. Things were going great until I noticed some errors due to depth testing:

Good from one angle

[image: Good from one angle]

Bad from another

[image: Bad from another]

Some research has brought me to these posts, but I am still trying to figure out how to apply their suggestions in a three.js environment:

[Rendering glitch with GL_DEPTH_TEST and transparent textures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353210/rendering-glitch-with-gl-depth-test-and-transparent-textures)

[Blending transparent textures with depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887858/blending-transparent-textures-with-depth/2892843#2892843)

As far as I know, `{transparent: true}` in a THREE.Material already separates transparent materials from opaque ones for proper rendering. However, I cannot get away with disabling depth writes because I don't have control over the rendering order of the transparent geometry (as far as I know). Am I missing something obvious that will help me out of this mess?

Comment: In typical fashion, I have found a solution just minutes after posting :P

All I had to do was add `alphaTest: 0.5` to the material and it sorted everything out nicely. Hopefully I haven't introduced more gotchas with this fix... _(knock on wood)_